# Cygwin responds with Permission Denied when I try to copy a file

Tags: cygwin

I am a complete beginner to Cygwin and am trying to copy a file.

```
cp /cygdrive/c/Users/name/Downloads/file_name .
```

Cygwin responds with

```
cp: cannot create regular file `./file_name': Permission denied
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have access to write to your current directory? You will need to check this by looking at the security properties for your current directory.

Comment: And your current working directory is...?

Comment: try https://superuser.com/questions/614237/permission-denied-when-using-mv-in-windows-7-cygwin?rq=1

Answer (score -2):

Try using:

```
sudo cp /cygdrive/c/Users/name/Downloads/file_name .
```

And entering your password when the prompt comes. If sudo doesn't work, try using "su" instead. As noted above, make sure you have write access on the directory you are in. If you go root (using sudo or su), you should automatically have write access. You could also just copy it over manually?

Comment: Did you read the question? `su` and `sudo`, while fine suggestions in any Linux environment, do not work in Cygwin, which is not Linux.